# Keras model behaves very differently between two computers

Tags: python, keras

I'm running a keras model for binary classification on two separate computers; the first is running python 2.7.5 with Tensorflow 1.0.1 and keras 2.0.2 and cpu computations; the second is running python 2.7.5 with Tensorflow 1.2.1 and keras 2.0.6 and uses the gpu.

My model is modified from the siamese network model at https://gist.github.com/mmmikael/0a3d4fae965bdbec1f9d. I added regularization (activity_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1 in the Dense layers), but for everything else I'm using the same structure as the mnist example.

I use the exact same code and training data on both computers, but the first one gives me a classification accuracy 86% and recall 88% on the test set, and the other gives me accuracy 52% and recall 100% (it classifies every test sample as "positive"). These results are reproducible with separate initializations.

I'm not even sure where to start looking for why the performance is so vastly different. I've been reading through the keras/tensorflow release notes to see if any of the changes pertain to something in my model, but I don't see anything that looks helpful. It doesn't make sense that a version change in tensorflow/keras would cause that much of a difference in the performance. Any sort of help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1 - Maybe it's a change in tensorflow? 2 - Have you tried to use the "CPU" instead of the GPU? If you've got very very little gradients, precision matters a lot. Make sure both models are using the same precision, such as "float32" for instance.

Comment: When I run model.get_weights(), both are float32. The input data is float64 in both cases. Forcing keras to run with cpu did not have any effect (thanks for the suggestion, though, I should have tried that first!)

Comment: I think this may be linked to how keras does regularization; I get comparable results on both computers when I decrease the regularization coefficient by a factor of 10,000 on the second one.

Comment: @snooze_bear Just wondering if you’ve learnt anything more about this performance difference? I’m experiencing something similar with identical versions of tensorflow giving very different performance on different computers, and any help on debugging this would be much appreciated